# How to show multiple items inside a single gridview template field?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to show multiple items in gridview inside a single template field column like this

```
item1                     item2

item3                     item4

item5                     item6

...                       ...
```

I mean displaying items in two columns instead of a single column.
default mode is like this:

```
item1

item2

item3

item4
```

Comment: Create a HTML table inside gridview Template field. Show us your code .

Comment: every item is a table including labels and images and <a> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The best solution is to use a `listview` control in which you can define a customized layout template [ListView Overview (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.ASPX)
2. Alternatively, you can drop several `label` controls inside a single gridview template field & dataBind them like this

`<asp:Label ID="lblItem1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("YourDataColumn1")%>'>
</asp:Label>`

Comment: thank you i think the list view is the solution. but it has no Style. why? how can i set its width?

Comment: You can apply a css class <asp:ListView CssClass="myClass" /> & style it via an external style sheet or inline styles.